# Edirectory Symfony Composer Install Package Conflict

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, edirectory

I am helping someone install E-Directory. It's overall a buggy app.

composer.json

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "src/ArcaSolutions/ModStoresBundle/Resources/functions/hookfire.php",
            "src/ArcaSolutions/ModStoresBundle/Resources/functions/hookexist.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "ArcaSolutions\\": "src/ArcaSolutions/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1",
        "ext-exif": "*",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-intl": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-mcrypt": "*",
        "ext-apcu": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-mysqli": "*",

        "symfony/symfony": "^2.8.*",
        "symfony/console": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.6",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "ruflin/elastica": "~3.1",
        "liip/theme-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "oyejorge/less.php": "~1.5",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.4.*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^5.3",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^1.5",
        "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.0",
        "tplaner/when": "2.*",
        "liip/imagine-bundle": "1.3.*",
        "gregwar/captcha-bundle": "1.1",
        "jms/translation-bundle": "1.3.1",
        "excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "1.4.1",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "~1.7",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "1.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.0",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^2.12",
        "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle": "1.5.*",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^3.13",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3",
        "facebook/graph-sdk": "^5.4",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "^1.8.1",
        "mixpanel/mixpanel-php" : "^2.6",
        "egeloen/google-map": "^2.0",
        "egeloen/google-map-bundle": "^3.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
        "awps/font-awesome-php": "^4.7",
        "leafo/scssphp": "0.7.6",
        "salva/jshrink-bundle": "^1.1",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.112"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.8.*",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "5.3.*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the message I get when I run composer update:

```
Dependency resolution completed in 24.324 seconds
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit 5.3.* -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.19 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.20 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.21 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.22 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.23 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.24 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.25 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.26 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.27 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.28 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.29 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.30 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.31 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.32 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.33 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.34 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.35 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.36 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.37 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.38 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.39 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.40 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.41 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.42 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.43 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.44 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.45 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.46 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.47 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.48 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.50 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.52 (conflict analysis result)
    - doctrine/orm[2.8.0, 2.8.1] require php ^7.2|^8.0 -> your php version (7.1.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/console[v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8] require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (7.1.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/console[v5.0.9, v5.0.10, v5.0.11, v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.3, v5.1.4, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.8, v5.1.9, v5.1.10, v5.2.0, v5.2.1] require php >=7.2.5 -> your php version (7.1.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.6 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.7 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.8 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.9 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.10 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.11 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.12 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.13 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.14 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.15 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.16 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.17 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.18 (conflict analysis result)
    - doctrine/orm[v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6] require symfony/console ~3.0|~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.1.10, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.16, v3.3.17, v3.3.18, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.2, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23, v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.29, v3.4.30, v3.4.31, v3.4.32, v3.4.33, v3.4.34, v3.4.35, v3.4.36, v3.4.37, v3.4.38, v3.4.39, v3.4.40, v3.4.41, v3.4.42, v3.4.43, v3.4.44, v3.4.45, v3.4.46, v3.4.47, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.0.10, v4.0.11, v4.0.12, v4.0.13, v4.0.14, v4.0.15, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.3.0, v4.3.1, v4.3.2, v4.3.3, v4.3.4, v4.3.5, v4.3.6, v4.3.7, v4.3.8, v4.3.9, v4.3.10, v4.3.11, v4.4.0, v4.4.1, v4.4.2, v4.4.3, v4.4.4, v4.4.5, v4.4.6, v4.4.7, v4.4.8, v4.4.9, v4.4.10, v4.4.11, v4.4.12, v4.4.13, v4.4.14, v4.4.15, v4.4.16, v4.4.17, v4.4.18].
    - doctrine/orm[v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.7.5] require symfony/console ^3.0|^4.0|^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.1.10, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.16, v3.3.17, v3.3.18, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.2, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23, v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.29, v3.4.30, v3.4.31, v3.4.32, v3.4.33, v3.4.34, v3.4.35, v3.4.36, v3.4.37, v3.4.38, v3.4.39, v3.4.40, v3.4.41, v3.4.42, v3.4.43, v3.4.44, v3.4.45, v3.4.46, v3.4.47, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.0.10, v4.0.11, v4.0.12, v4.0.13, v4.0.14, v4.0.15, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.3.0, v4.3.1, v4.3.2, v4.3.3, v4.3.4, v4.3.5, v4.3.6, v4.3.7, v4.3.8, v4.3.9, v4.3.10, v4.3.11, v4.4.0, v4.4.1, v4.4.2, v4.4.3, v4.4.4, v4.4.5, v4.4.6, v4.4.7, v4.4.8, v4.4.9, v4.4.10, v4.4.11, v4.4.12, v4.4.13, v4.4.14, v4.4.15, v4.4.16, v4.4.17, v4.4.18, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.0.9, v5.0.10, v5.0.11, v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.3, v5.1.4, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.8, v5.1.9, v5.1.10, v5.2.0, v5.2.1].
    - Only one of these can be installed: symfony/console[2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, v2.0.9, v2.0.10, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.3.3, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.4.10, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.40, v2.7.41, v2.7.42, v2.7.43, v2.7.44, v2.7.45, v2.7.46, v2.7.47, v2.7.48, v2.7.49, v2.7.50, v2.7.51, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.49, v2.8.50, v2.8.52, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.1.10, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.16, v3.3.17, v3.3.18, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.2, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23, v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.29, v3.4.30, v3.4.31, v3.4.32, v3.4.33, v3.4.34, v3.4.35, v3.4.36, v3.4.37, v3.4.38, v3.4.39, v3.4.40, v3.4.41, v3.4.42, v3.4.43, v3.4.44, v3.4.45, v3.4.46, v3.4.47, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.0.10, v4.0.11, v4.0.12, v4.0.13, v4.0.14, v4.0.15, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.3.0, v4.3.1, v4.3.2, v4.3.3, v4.3.4, v4.3.5, v4.3.6, v4.3.7, v4.3.8, v4.3.9, v4.3.10, v4.3.11, v4.4.0, v4.4.1, v4.4.2, v4.4.3, v4.4.4, v4.4.5, v4.4.6, v4.4.7, v4.4.8, v4.4.9, v4.4.10, v4.4.11, v4.4.12, v4.4.13, v4.4.14, v4.4.15, v4.4.16, v4.4.17, v4.4.18, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.0.9, v5.0.10, v5.0.11, v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.3, v5.1.4, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.8, v5.1.9, v5.1.10, v5.2.0, v5.2.1], symfony/symfony[v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.49, v2.8.50, v2.8.51, v2.8.52]. symfony/symfony replaces symfony/console and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/symfony 2.8.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.49, v2.8.50, v2.8.51, v2.8.52].
    - Root composer.json requires doctrine/orm ^2.6 -> satisfiable by doctrine/orm[v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.7.5, 2.8.0, 2.8.1].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

Could someone please explain what I should do next? I've been struggling for hours, eliminating dependencies, putting specific versions, etc.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Update: I tried

```
$composer install
```

this is what I got

```
# composer install
The "ocramius/package-versions" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.0.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Continue as root/super user [yes]? yes
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - ocramius/package-versions is locked to version 1.4.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - ocramius/package-versions 1.4.2 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 2
    - ocramius/package-versions 1.4.2 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
    - ocramius/proxy-manager 2.1.1 requires ocramius/package-versions ^1.1.1 -> satisfiable by ocramius/package-versions[1.4.2].
    - ocramius/proxy-manager is locked to version 2.1.1 and an update of this package was not requested.

ocramius/package-versions only provides support for Composer 2 in 1.8+, which requires PHP 7.4.
If you can not upgrade PHP you can require composer/package-versions-deprecated to resolve this with PHP 7.0+.

You are using Composer 2, which some of your plugins seem to be incompatible with. Make sure you update your plugins or report a plugin-issue to ask them to support Composer 2.
```

I also tried eliminating symfony-console as a requirement and ran
$composer update This is what I got:

```
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle 1.4.1 -> satisfiable by excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle[v1.4.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.6 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.7 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.8 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.9 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle v1.4.1 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.4.10, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.40, v2.7.41, v2.7.42, v2.7.43, v2.7.44, v2.7.45, v2.7.46, v2.7.47, v2.7.48, v2.7.49, v2.7.50, v2.7.51, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.49, v2.8.50, v2.8.52].
    - Only one of these can be installed: symfony/framework-bundle[2.0.7, v2.0.9, v2.0.10, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.3.3, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.4.10, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.40, v2.7.41, v2.7.42, v2.7.43, v2.7.44, v2.7.45, v2.7.46, v2.7.47, v2.7.48, v2.7.49, v2.7.50, v2.7.51, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.49, v2.8.50, v2.8.52, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.2, v3.1.3, v3.1.4, v3.1.5, v3.1.6, v3.1.7, v3.1.8, v3.1.9, v3.1.10, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.16, v3.3.17, v3.3.18, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.2, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23, v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.29, v3.4.30, v3.4.31, v3.4.32, v3.4.33, v3.4.34, v3.4.35, v3.4.36, v3.4.37, v3.4.38, v3.4.39, v3.4.40, v3.4.41, v3.4.42, v3.4.43, v3.4.44, v3.4.45, v3.4.46, v3.4.47, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.0.10, v4.0.11, v4.0.12, v4.0.13, v4.0.14, v4.0.15, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.3.0, v4.3.1, v4.3.2, v4.3.3, v4.3.4, v4.3.5, v4.3.6, v4.3.7, v4.3.8, v4.3.9, v4.3.10, v4.3.11, v4.4.0, v4.4.1, v4.4.2, v4.4.3, v4.4.4, v4.4.5, v4.4.6, v4.4.7, v4.4.8, v4.4.9, v4.4.10, v4.4.11, v4.4.12, v4.4.13, v4.4.14, v4.4.15, v4.4.16, v4.4.17, v4.4.18], symfony/symfony[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9]. symfony/symfony replaces symfony/framework-bundle and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/symfony 3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6, v3.0.7, v3.0.8, v3.0.9].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

I downgraded to v1.1:

```
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                        
  The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle%244a31b3713294f9e468e13e0c03810776095325113d004f45f416fb6e8e12af89.json"  
   file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
```

Comment: I installed php7.1 on purpose, because the instructions said so.

Comment: You have to install locked dependencies using command `composer install`. Hasn't it worked for you?

Comment: `doctrine/orm[2.8.0, 2.8.1] require php ^7.2|^8.0` - anything unclear about that?

Comment: Your `composer install` output suggests you should downgrade to composer v1. Use `composer self-update --1` or download it from the website: https://getcomposer.org/download/ (scroll down for other versions)

Comment: webmaster777 this is what I got:  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                        
  The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle%244a31b3713294f9e468e13e0c03810776095325113d004f45f416fb6e8e12af89.json"  
   file could not be downloaded:

Comment: I resolved many issues. I upvoted everyone and gave credit when I can. I started another question because I ran out of space. Thank you all.

Comment: Here is the second question: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65732247/edirectory-symphony-composer-install-package-conflict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requiring both `"symfony/symfony": "^2.8.*"` and `"symfony/console": "^3.0"` does not work, as `symfony/console` is a component that is also part of `symfony/symfony`. You need to get rid of one of this requirements.

If you face any further problems, please share the error message occurring after this first fix

Comment: I shared the error messages in the original comment. Please help.